# How get time or real value persent of uploading file in Telerik RadUpload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

My project uses the Telerik upload file control with manager:

```
<telerik:RadUpload ID="RadUpload" Runat="server" MaxFileInputsCount="5" />
<telerik:RadProgressManager ID="RadProgressManager" Runat="server" />
```

On the client side I want to display a progress bar with jQuery UI:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetRadUpload() { return $find("<%=RadUpload.ClientID %>"); }
    function GetRadProgressManager() { return $find("<%=RadProgressManager.ClientID %>"); }

    $('#upload_buttonSubmit').click(function() {
        var upload = GetRadUpload();
        var fileInputs = upload.getFileInputs();
        var M = GetRadProgressManager();
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: ??? });
    });        
</script>
```

I need to get a percent complete from `RadUpload`/`RadProgressManager` or get the time needed to upload the file.  How can I get one of these values?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/upload/examples/customprogress/defaultcs.aspx), they have the progress all built in with very little code.  Does the built in Progress Manager not fit your needs?

Comment: In my project on telerik windows it do not work, I can't find reason why.

Comment: Maybe best to go post on the forum over at [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/upload.aspx)  They can get you what you need.